# How to get percentage from 2 tables using SQL

Tags: sql, hql, impala

i'm working on my project using impala. and i have 2 different tables, my purpose is to get as output result contains compteur-name following by percent of all months 2016 and then 2017 so i can get a comparative view.

```
+----------+----------+------------+---------+--------------+
| compteur |   jan2016| feb2016    | mars2016 |    avr2016  | ...
+----------+----------+------------+---------+--------------+
|  5510    |7760250   |   56840    |          |   5000      |
|  3200    |7865000   |   894650   |          |   850       |
|  4850    |3596825   |   687970   |          |   7860      |
|  5500    |4589350   |   55256    |    5000  |    6698     |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+
```

my second table :

```
    +----------+----------+------------+---------+--------------+
| compteur |   jan2017| feb2017    | mars2017 |    avr2017  | ...
+----------+----------+------------+---------+--------------+
|  5510    |568050    |   56840    | 589744   |   5000      |
|  3200    |5000      |   894650   |   456242 |   850       |
|  4850    |3899825   |   687970   |  4578    |   7860      |
|  5500    |4589350   |   55256    |    5000  |    6698     |
+----------+----------+------------+---------+---------+
```

what i want is this :

```
 +------+---------------+-----------+
| COmpteur |    % of 2016  | % of 2017 |
+-------+------------------+-----------+
|   5510   |      %        |  %        |
|   3200   |       %       |  %        |
|   4850   |        %      |  %        |
|   5500   |          %    |  %       |
+----------+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What is the logic for calculate % of 2016?

Comment: Result example is not clear.

Comment: "by percent of all months 2016 and then 2017" is not clear.